# Clickhouse create jdbc engine table?

Tags: clickhouse

```sql
CREATE TABLE jdbc_table 
ENGINE = JDBC('jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.16:4307/?user=root&password=root', 'test', 'test')
```

this statement gets error

> Syntax error: failed at position 114 (end of query):
>
> CREATE TABLE jdbc_table ENGINE =
>   JDBC('jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.16:4307/?user=root&password=root',
>   'test', 'test')
>
> Expected one of: AS, SETTINGS, TTL, PARTITION BY, PRIMARY KEY, ORDER
>   BY, SAMPLE BY

I don't know why.

Comment: I think you should open a new issue in https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues. The syntax seems valid according to docs. I checked CH repo and found no tests for JDBC engine, might be broken.

Comment: make sure that [ClickHouse JDBC bridge](https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc-bridge) is running and try to execute the query: *select * from jdbc('jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.16:4307/?user=root&password=root', 'test', 'test')*. As alternative, try to define the columns-definitions in *create table*-statement.

Answer (score 3):

Documentation is incorrect. `Create table` needs a columns list (e.g. (A String, B UInt32)).

```
create table jdbc.category engine 
= JDBC('datasource://postgresql', 'public', 'category')
as select * from jdbc('datasource://postgresql', 'public', 'category');
```

or

```
create table jdbc.category(A String, B UInt32) 
engine = JDBC('datasource://postgresql', 'public', 'category')
```

Comment: Thanks!
I also found this.
create table remote_table as  remote('IP:port','DB','table')
This statement works!

Comment: @StephenXia that notation is for remote clickhouse servers, not for JDBC.